# Cart2Quote Quotations error: Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'class': The attribute 'class' is not allowed

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, third-party-module

- I got an error after installing cart2Quote free
- (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'class': The attribute 'class' is not allowed.
- i am using magento 2.2.7
  Please help!
  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two allowed attributes for reference blocks.

> remove
>
> display

Search for **referenceBlock** in your cart2quote module and remove the `class` attribute from **referenceBlock** element.

Flush your Magento cache `php bin/magento c:f` and check.

Comment: thank your answer!
i has remove all class attribute from referenceBlock, but it not working for me.

Comment: make sure to flush all cache and then check.

Comment: yes. i has flush all cache but it not working.

Comment: this is my mistake. I mistook referenceBlock vs referenceContainer

Comment: glad it helps you. please accept and upvote the answer if helpful.

Comment: yes i has vote for you.
I want to ask one more question.
Does the class I delete in referenceBlock affect anything?

Comment: yes, it will not add the class in that reference block html.